# On Button click i want to toggle the text of TextView

Tags: java, android

I want to toggle textview text with on a button click .I have set the flag as public variable and change it in onclick function but still the value of flag for some reason is initialized to its default value. i am beginner to android studio
Thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public Button bt1;
public TextView txt;
public boolean flag;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bt1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(flag){
                flag=false;
                txt.setText("Steve");
            }
            else {
                txt.setText("Shetty");
                flag=true;
            }

        }
    });

 }
 }
```

I want text of Textview to toggle every time i click on the button but text of textview changes only once.

Answer (score 0):

flag is Always true and the text is Always set to "Steve"

```
flag=true;
if(flag=true){
flag=false;
txt.setText("Steve");
}
else {
txt.setText("Shetty");
flag=true;
}
```

try to initialize flag with true and remove the flag = true part inside your onClickListener

```
flag = true;
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

if(flag=true){
flag=false;
txt.setText("Steve");
}
else {
txt.setText("Shetty");
flag=true;
}

}
});
```

Comment: please recheck the code. I edited it but still it is not working

Comment: you forgot to initialize flag

Comment: default value if 0 or false no need to initilize

Answer (score 0):

That is because you defined the variable "flag" in the local scope. Meaning that when you modify the flag variable and you go out of the local scope (exiting the onClick method), the flag variable no longer exists. So the change that you made is not reflected the next time it goes to the onClick method. (You are also setting the value of the variable at the start, so of course the if statement always evaluates to True) To fix this problem, define the flag variable outside of onClick() method where it is accessible.

```
boolean flag;

bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(flag){
            flag=false;
            txt.setText("Steve");
        }
        else {
            txt.setText("Shetty");
            flag=true;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: please recheck the code. I edited it but still it is not working

Comment: What do you mean by not working. The code above runs fine.

Comment: it is switches only once steven. i want it to toggle every time i click the button

Comment: It should not switch once zaid. I don't think you understood what you did wrong. If you compared your original code and the code above, you should be able to understand why your code does not work. Don't blindly copy and paste code from the internet. Actually take the time to understand what you did wrong and how you can fix it. I am merely telling you what you did wrong and gave you an example of how to fix it. The code above does switch multiple times zaid.